# How does the Open Atrium Wizard work?

Tags: views, distributions

*Okay, this might seem noobish, and I doubt questions like this often get answered, but:*

**How do you create a simple Wizard in Open Atrium?**

I am not really sure how the Wizard feature(?) in Open Atrium works. Haven't seen any tutorials or other documentation for how the heck this thing behaves, or can be created. So any example on this "thing", would be kindly accepted.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Having seen your other question about mind mapping, I got to tell you this: your question lacks details. There is one form API that every module uses to create forms. And we don't use the "wizard" word a lot because a Wizard is either the Gandalf type or really a multi step form. In latter case, you will probably need to write a module for that.  Screenshots, and module names would be helpful for other to understand what components you refer to.

Comment: @AyeshK.  "Wizard" *is* the name of the module.  Rather "Open Atrium Wizard," to be precise.  And yes, there is ostensibly no documentation for it.